# No me funciona el query

Tags: android, firebase, sql

Estoy teniendo problemas en como hacer funcionar esta query.

```
public class MasculinoClient extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TAG = "TAG";
FirebaseFirestore fStore;
private CollectionReference jugadoresRef;
private JugadoresMasc_Adapter adapter;


//Toolbar toolbar;

FirebaseAuth fAuth;
String userId, userClub;
DocumentReference userRef;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_masculino_client);
    this.setTitle("Padron Masculino");

    fAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    fStore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

    userId = fAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
    jugadoresRef = fStore.collection("Padron");

    ClubUser();
    //PadronMasculinoClient();
}

private void ClubUser() {
    userRef = fStore.collection("Usuarios").document(userId);
    userRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                DocumentSnapshot clubvalue = task.getResult();
                if (clubvalue.exists()) {
                    userClub = clubvalue.getString("CLUB");
                    PadronMasculinoClient(userClub);
                    Log.d(TAG, "CLUB VALUE: " + userClub);
                    Toast.makeText(MasculinoClient.this, "Se obtuvo el valor Club", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MasculinoClient.this, "El documento no existe", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "get failed with ", task.getException());
            }
        }
    });
}

private void PadronMasculinoClient(String userClub) {
    Query query = jugadoresRef
            .orderBy("APELLIDO", Query.Direction.ASCENDING)
            .whereEqualTo("SEXO", "MASCULINO")
            .whereEqualTo("CLUB", userClub);

    FirestoreRecyclerOptions<JugadoresMasc> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<JugadoresMasc>()
            .setQuery(query, JugadoresMasc.class)
            .build();

    adapter = new JugadoresMasc_Adapter(options);

    RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_masculino_client);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    Log.d(TAG, "QUERY: " + query);
    Log.d(TAG, "ADAPTER: " + adapter);
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    adapter.startListening();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    adapter.stopListening();
}
```

}

Utilizo la función "CubUser" para capturar en un String el value "CLUB" del usuario que necesitaría usar en la query (PadronMasculinoClient) para que busque los documentos que contengan ese mismo value.

Ejemplo: El usuario "Paula" del Club Colon (key - "CLUB", value - Colon) ingresa a la app a ver el padron de jugadores (solo deben ver los jugadores (documentos de la collection "Padron") del club Colon), que tienen los mismos key-value que los users, por ende el query deberia poder filtrar por el club correspondiente de cada usuario, de una forma automatizda ya que hay usuarios de diferentes clubes.

Cuando ejecuto la app esa query no me muestra nada, no crashea la app ni da error, pero no me muestra ningún valor.

Como podría resolver esto?

Le pase el "debug" y me tira esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y esto me tira el logcat al momento de abrir el activity del query:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí agrego la estructura de datos de Cloud Firestore:
Estructura Usuarios:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estructura Padron:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En otra estructura en Realtime Database, tengo la estructura de los nombres de los Clubes a usar en un spinner solo para la pantalla de creacion de jugadores o usuarios, para que de esta forma siempre se mantengan escritos de la misma forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto tambien es ya que puede haber modificaciones de Clubes, mas o menos y de esta forma me ahorro tener que modificar el programa, solo modifico la base de datos. Si existe otra manera seria bueno saberlo.

Ese codigo me da el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agrego codigo de adapter:

```
public class JugadoresMasc_Adapter extends FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<JugadoresMasc, JugadoresMasc_Adapter.ListaHolder> {

public JugadoresMasc_Adapter(@NonNull FirestoreRecyclerOptions<JugadoresMasc> options) {
    super(options);
}

@Override
protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ListaHolder holder, int position, @NonNull JugadoresMasc model) {
    holder.tv_apellido_player.setText(model.getAPELLIDO());
    holder.tv_nombre_player.setText(model.getNOMBRE());
    holder.tv_dni_player.setText(model.getDNI());
    holder.tv_club_player.setText(model.getCLUB());
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ListaHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.lista_jugadores, parent, false);
    return new ListaHolder(v);
}

class ListaHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView tv_apellido_player, tv_nombre_player, tv_dni_player, tv_club_player;

    public ListaHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        tv_apellido_player = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_apellido_player);
        tv_nombre_player = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_nombre_player);
        tv_dni_player = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_dni_player);
        tv_club_player = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_club_player);
    }
}

public void deleteItem(int position) {
    getSnapshots().getSnapshot(position).getReference().delete();
}
```

}

Comment: ¿Haz revisado el Logcat? Haz un log de `clubvalue` y dinos qué muestra.

Comment: log en la funcion ClubUser, solo poniendo clubvalue me muestra esto:   DocumentSnapshot{key=Usuarios/K6mTxQbgnNeKqt3eeTVmfvB6RZu2, metadata=SnapshotMetadata{hasPendingWrites=false, isFromCache=false}, doc=Document{key=Usuarios/K6mTxQbgnNeKqt3eeTVmfvB6RZu2, data=com.google.firebase.firestore.model.ObjectValue@b1a81095, version=SnapshotVersion(seconds=1591393612, nanos=609755000), documentState=SYNCED}}

Comment: en la misma funcion poniendo .getData:    DocumentSnapshot: {APELLIDO=Amigo, PASSWORD=123456, CLUB=Colon SF, EMAIL=paula@yo.org, TYPE=Client, NOMBRE=Paula} y poniento .getString (que en teoria es el value que estoy solicitando: DocumentSnapshot: Colon SF

Comment: Los datos parecen estar llegando bien, pero no logro comprender qué quieres hacer en concreto. Esto es confuso, sobre todo la parte en negritas: *Utilizo la función "CubUser" para capturar en un String el value "CLUB" del usuario **que necesitaría usar en la query (PadronMasculinoClient) para que busque los documentos que contengan ese mismo value**.* Por favor pulsa en [edit] para explicar mejor qué quieres hacer con los datos.

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110241/discussion-on-question-by-nicox-no-me-funciona-el-query).